# Will the Reset PC option on windows 8.1 will erase other partitons other than C:?

Tags: windows, reset, partition

I recently had an error and the Reset PC option seems promising. But would it erase other partitons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Resetting the PC would not erase the partitions, but only the personal files and apps in your system except the factory default apps.

I did not find any exact page or thread saying that. But the list of things that would happen on resetting a pc given in these links gives an idea of what level of clean up is done.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03546603